# Andersen's Pointer Analysis with Soot

Tags: java, pointers, soot

I am interested in building Andersen's pointer analysis for Java with Soot, a compiler infrastructure framework. Following are the papers in this area. I am unable to identify a proper approach to start and program this analysis for Java. Can anyone help me with this?

An Efficient Inclusion-Based Points-To Analysis for Strictly-Typed Languages
http://suif.stanford.edu/~jwhaley/papers/sas02.pdf

Program Analysis and Specialization for the C Programming Language (Original Andersen’s analysis Thesis)
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs711/2005fa/papers/andersen-thesis94.pdf

Points-To for Java: A General Framework and an Empirical Comparison
https://pp.info.uni-karlsruhe.de/uploads/publikationen/streckenbach00tr.pdf

Scaling Java Points-To Analysis using Spark
https://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~olhotak/pubs/sable-tr-2002-9.pdf

Points-to Analysis for Java Using Annotated Constraints
http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~milanova/docs/oopsla01.pdf

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No need to build it, it's already in Soot. Just use the -w flag.

Comment: But the aim is to build it. Not to use the already provided one.